# I want to make AJAX call in WordPress irrespective of user is logged in or not

Tags: wordpress

I want to make AJAX call in WordPress irrespective of user is logged in or not ! How to do so ?
Coz wp_ajax_ is firing only for authenitcated user 
wp_ajax_nopriv is firing only for unauthenticated user.

Is there any hook or any way which will fire AJAX for both whether user is logged in or not logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use both hook:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'your_function' ) ) :

    function your_function() {

        // Nonce
        $nonce = $_REQUEST['nonce'];
        // Parameter 1
        $param1 = $_REQUEST['yourParam1'];

        // Verify nonce
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, "yourNonceName") )
            wp_send_json( __("No snitch!", TEMPLATE_DOMAIN) );

        // ... your requests for results ...

        // Show results
        if ( !empty($result) )
            wp_send_json( $result );
        else
            wp_send_json( __("Error!", TEMPLATE_DOMAIN) );

        die();
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_function', 'your_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function', 'your_function' );
```

In your js file:

```
$('#your-btn').click(function() {
    // Nonce
    var yourNonce = $(this).data("nonce");
    // param1 value
    var yourParam1 = $('#param1').val();

    // Data to send
    var data = {
        'action': 'your_function',
        'nonce': yourNonce,
        "yourParam1": yourParam1,
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : MainJS.ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
            // Add loading text
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function( res ) {
            // Your data results
        }
    });
 });
```

In your page:

```
echo '<button id="your-btn" data-nonce="' . wp_create_nonce( "yourNonceName" ) . '">Test</button>';
```

Otherwise there is a better way in my opinion and that is use the REST API:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'yourSlug/v1', '/test/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'yourSlug_test_callback'
    ) );
} );

function yourSlug_test_callback( $request ) {
    $param = $request['param'];
    $response = "Received " . esc_html( $param );
    return new WP_REST_Response($response);
}
```

Now if you flush permalinks you'll find a new endpoint at

> mySite.com/wp-json/yourSlug/v1/test

and when you do a POST request to it, you get back a JSON.

Comment: This answer assumes a bunch of information. You could cut down this answer to: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_function', 'your_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function', 'your_function' );` Since WP's documentation has this information.